# Euro Truck Simulator Standard Telemetry Format

Tags: data-structure, simulations, protocol, telemetry

My son's enjoying Euro Truck Simulator 2 on a Windows PC. I've ben looking a the SDK to extend its functionality. I thought it would be useful to serve the telemetry and build a physical dashboard around it.

It seems several folk have already developed such servers, however the version my son prefers is by Stryder-IT and it allows him to create a "dashboard" on his tablet using their own app.

In reading through the documentation, it became clear to me that many console-based simulation games publish telemetry data, including Euro Truck Simulator 2. The Windows versions of these games don't tend to; they require this additional server shim, which presumably accesses the telemetry using a shared memory method, and republishes it by TCP/IP.

Specifically, my aim would be to connect to the server using a raspberry Pi, which would control several actual physical truck gauges which I have acquired.

I want to grab the telemetry data from the Stryder-IT program, but I can't see the protocol documented anywhere. Not even the IP port number. **It strikes me that if this ability is built into some console games, then there must be some kind of standard.**

Question is: where can it be found?

I don't even know if I'm correct in my assertion that there must be a standard: If there was, does it have a name? It would seem odd if it was some kind of closed, proprietary protocol.

I have noted that if I try to forward the ETS2 telemetry by UDP using the Stryder-IT server, the ETS2 game does not appear on the list. There is a note that if it's not on the list, it doesn't require forwarding of telemetry. This implies to me that it's already sending telemetry. Is this a sensible conclusion? How could I find out the protocol?

Thanks.